# REST Adapter model reloading

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm having some difficulty reloading my ember RESTful models, and I'm not sure why.  Here's [conceptually] what I'm trying to do... http://jsbin.com/EfuBiNo/4/edit

The only difference between that code and my code is that I'm not using the FixtureAdapter, I'm using the RESTAdapter.  Unfortunately, reloading my RESTful models is causing the number of records in the DS.RecordArray to double.  So you can see the console is logging that (on every reload) there are two records in the RecordArray.

When I run this with my RestAdapter, the count goes 2...4...8...16....etc.  So I'm not sure why it's doubling them every time, but if anybody has any insight on why -- or better yet, another way to reload these records -- I'd be very grateful.   Thanks.

Comment: I updated your jsbin to use the rest adapter, but worked for me. Please give a look http://jsbin.com/EfuBiNo/7/edit. Maybe you are missing something in the jsbin, or your server is returning additional data...

Comment: Is your server returning an id property for each resource? And most importantly, is it returning the same id for the same resource every time?

Comment: Thanks Marcio, ahaurw01 -- it was the missing id.  In the database, but not in the record returned from the server.  Adding that solved the issue.  Though I'm still wondering if there isn't a better way to do this.  Each record updating this way issues a new request.  Do you know if there's a way to reload all the models in the RecordArray at once?  Am I looking at this the wrong way?

Comment: I'd be curious why you need to force an update of records you've already loaded into your local store. If you are looking for real-time updates, I'd suggest using websockets (and a customized adapter) to accomplish this instead of polling the server by constantly reloading records.

Comment: ahaurw01 -- this is for a call center type app.  Messages get placed in a queue, then get dealt with, and updates get sent to the UI.  As for websocket based updates -- yes, this is on my radar.

Comment: @sentinel21 you can do `calls.update()` instead of `calls.forEach ...`   and reload each model.

Comment: @Marcio, calls.update doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to refresh a collection of records after you've already loaded them, you could do something like:

```
App.ThingsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function () {
    return this.store.find('thing');
  },

  actions: {
    refreshThings: function () {
      var controller = this.controller;
      this.store.find('thing').then(function (things) {
        controller.set('content', things);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

This will simply fetch all the `thing`s again and set the record array as the content on your controller whenever the promise resolves. If the items that come back are already catalogued in your store (the ids are already present) then you won't get a ton of duplicate records hanging around; stuff will just get updated. If there are new records that you didn't previously know about, then you'll get those now on your `ThingsController`.

This is also useful if you are doing some type of querying:

```
this.store.find('thing', {color: 'red'})
```

Comment: you bet! Sockets sound a lot more fun than this, tho :)

Comment: Hi. How would you implement it for regular refresh (e.g. every 10 secs)? Thanks.